# What's the purpose of beforeAll() in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jasmine

Why should we not just replace `beforeAll(function(){ let foo = 'test' })` with `let foo = 'test'` ?  What's the purpose of `beforeAll` if the second way is fine?

Here's the official definition by the way: The beforeAll function executes once and only once for the describe block containing it, before any of the beforeEach functions or any of the specs.

Comment: You can. In fact, if you want to access `foo` from outside the `beforeAll` function, you must. `beforeAll` is for things you want to instantiate before any of the tests run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some substantial differences between `beforeAll` block and plain code in the scope of `describe` function.

`beforeAll` setup is supposed to be coupled with `afterAll` teardown.

Errors in `before*` blocks are not critical and won't prevent the list of specs from being populated and specs from being run. An error in `describe` block will result in empty list of specs.

`before*` and `it` blocks have [`this` as the context of current spec](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-The_%3Ccode%3Ethis%3C/code%3E_keyword) which can be used as recommended way to share data between blocks. It is generally more preferable than plain variables from parent scope because there's no risk to cross-contaminate tests this way. `describe` function doesn't have this context. However, this approach isn't compatible with ES6 arrow functions.

There may be Jasmine helpers that are supposed to be work in conjunction with `before*` and `it` blocks, e.g. in Angular testing:

```
beforeAll(fakeAsync(() => {
  asyncInitializationThatDoesntNeedDoneCallback();
}));
```

If it is a constant that should be defined for the entire block, then it can surely be defined without `beforeAll`:

```
describe('...', () => {
  const foo = 'test'; // not let
  ...
});
```